# How does pandas do sorting

Tags: python, pandas

At a high-level, how does pandas do sorting? For example, if I had the following dataframe:

```
l = [{
      'Name': 'Todd',
      'Age': 20,
     }, {
      'Name': 'Sarah',
      'Age': 25,
 }, {
      'Name': 'Sarah',
      'Age': 29,
 }]
df = pd.DataFrame(l)
df.sort_values(by=['Name', 'Age'])
```

Is this using a python built-in, such as:

```
sorted(l, key = lambda x: (x['Name'], x['Age']))
```

Or is the pandas sort something more complex? What is its basic implementation?

Comment: [`df.sort_values` source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.0.3/pandas/core/frame.py#L4896-L4946) Might give an insight.

Comment: No, it doesn't use `sorted`. It basically calls `numpy.ndarray.argsort`

Comment: Note, the built-in sort *is quite complex under the hood*. it is a highly-tuned adaptive merge sort called Timsort which is quite fast.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga -- I see, yea it looks like it leverages `numpy` quite a bit for some of the algorithmic stuff. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga here's where it specifies it: https://imgur.com/a/MM5gtPZ

Comment: @David542 yes, `pandas` is basically a wrapper around `numpy` to provided labelled indexes in two dimensional numpy arrays

Comment: @David542 well, that's just the argument forwarded to the numpy function